# async function doesn't wait of inside await in nodejs

Tags: node.js, async-await, promise

I am implementing function monthlyRevenue.
Simply, it will return total monthly revenue,and it takes arguments of station array which will make revenues, month and year.

**Problem**
Inside of this function I have getStationPortion which will fetch the revenue portion of user's.
So I would like to make it return object like this.

stationsPortion = {station1 : 30, station2 : 20}

In the monthlyRevenue

```
const stationPortions = await getStationPortions(stations)
console.log("portion map", stationPortions      //it will be shown very beginning with empty
```

getStationPortions

```
const getStationPortions = async (stations) => {
  let stationPortions = {}
  stations.map(async (value) => {
    const doc = await fdb.collection('Stations').doc(value).get()
    if (!doc.exists) {
      console.log("NO DOC")

    } else {
      stationPortions[value] = doc.data().salesPortion
      console.log(stationPortions)                   //it will be shown at the last.
    }
  })
  return stationPortions
}
```

I thought that async function should wait for the result, but it does not.
I am kind of confusing if my understanding is wrong.
Thank you
(by the way, fdb is firebase admin(firestore)

Comment: You shouldn't even be using `.map()` here as this seems like simple iteration. If not, you should use `Promise.all()`.

Answer (score 1):

**Working code**

```
const getStationPortions = async (stations) => {
  let stationPortions = {}
  await Promise.all(stations.map(async (value) => {
    const doc = await fdb.collection('Stations').doc(value).get()
    if (!doc.exists) {
      console.log("NO DOC")
    } else {
      stationPortions[value] = doc.data().salesPortion
      console.log(stationPortions)
    }
  }))
  return stationPortions
}
module.exports = router;
```